# currentUser is displayed undefined but defines later. This works in another component but not this specific one and I am unsure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am attempting to fetch current user information from database. However, for some odd reason it says the currentUser is undefined but when I debug it is defined after the function is called. Any ideas what could be a solution?

```
setResults(){
    const user = (this.props.firebase.auth.currentUser) ? this.props.firebase.auth.currentUser.uid : null ;
    if(user){
    this.props.firebase.result(this.props.firebase.auth.currentUser.uid).on('value', snapshot => {
      const resultObj = snapshot.val();
      if(resultObj) {
        const resultList = Object.keys(resultObj).map(key => ({
          ...resultObj[key],
        }));
        this.setState({
          result: resultList,
        loading: false,
        });
      }else{
        this.setState({ results: null, loading: false});
      }
    })
  }
}

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true});
    this.setResults();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`firebase.auth.currentUser` is always going to be undefined at the first moment code starts running on a web page load.  If a user is actually signed in, some brief time later, it will be populated with that user's identity.

What you should do is use an [auth state observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) to set up a callback when the user's sign-in state is known.  Your code should use this callback to determine when the user object is known, and when to start rendering content based on that user's data.

```
firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    var displayName = user.displayName;
    var email = user.email;
    var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
    var photoURL = user.photoURL;
    var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
    var uid = user.uid;
    var providerData = user.providerData;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
    // ...
  }
});
```